# Sql выбрать из массива значения, которых нет в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Мне надо написать функцию, в которую можно передать массив и она вернёт значения из таблицы, которых нет в массиве.
Например, массив `names_array = ['Kirill', 'Masha', 'Dasha']`
И есть таблица, например, студенты:

```
student(
    student_id bigserial primary key,
    student_first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    student_last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    something text DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Хотелось бы что-то, вроде,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(names_array text[] )
  RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  result := SELECT name FROM names_array WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT student_first_name FROM student);

  return result;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

И если в таблицу нет студентов Кирилла(ов), но есть Даша и Маша (а может их вообще несколько), то `result = ['Kirill']`

Comment: `array_remove()`

Comment: Хотелось бы немного более подробного ответа, но в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035) Особенно п. 2.3.